# f# get list of values from a collection

Tags: list, collections, f#

I'm in the very early stages of learning f# and I have come up with the following scenario.  I need to loop through a collection of email objects and create a list of the CC property for each email.  I know this is ideal for f# and yet I can't seem to find anything explaining how.  I think my google-fu just isn't good enough, could someone point me in the right direction?

Edit

So basically I want to map 1 type of MailMessage object to a different type.  The first type has the CC field as an ICollection of MailAddress objects.  The second type requires the CC field to be a list of strings.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output? It isn't clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
type Email = { Body : string }
// create some emails
let emails = Seq.init 10 (fun i -> { Body = string i })
// get list of bodies
let bodies = emails |> Seq.map (fun { Body = body } -> body) |> Seq.toList
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have an `Email` type modelled as F# records:

```
type Email = 
  { Subject: string;
    Body: string; }
```

and a list of emails:

```
let emails =
  [ {Subject = "Subject 1"; Body = "Body 1"};
    {Subject = "Subject 2"; Body = "Body 2"};
    {Subject = "Subject 3"; Body = "Body 3"}; ]
```

you can use high-order functions in List module to manipulate `emails`:

```
let bodies = emails |> List.map (fun e -> e.Body)
// val bodies = ["Body 1"; "Body 2"; "Body 3"]
```

To get started, please take a look at some MSDN materials on relevant topics:

- [Records](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx)
- [Basic list processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx)
- [List module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353738.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, both answers combined gave me a small Eureka moment when I realised what is going on!  I need to use Seq.map for an ICollection as Daniel suggested.  Slowly getting there :)